# Why is the text in a button always centered vertically?

Tags: html, css, layout, typography

I want to style a div exactly like a button. I noticed that when I give the button a specific height, the text is always centered vertically.

So far i tried digging through the Chromium user agent stylesheets but was not successful. `-webkit-appereance: button` also did not do the trick.

Here is a demo of the issue: https://codepen.io/franzskuffka/pen/QzqKQx. Note that the inline-block styling gives makes sure the text is aligned vertically - the bounding box is still weird.

Which property makes the text centered vertically without any additional wrappers? What is going on here?

Comment: It's called browser default styles. Like body margin, `<p />` margin etc. You can make text centered for example via `line-height`, with flex property `align-items: center`, with `padding`, ....

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote? This is not a 'fix my code question' but rather a research question. I am trying to figure out why an element that does not is not displayed as flex is still centering its text vertically - without any padding styles.

It would be interesting to know because this could vastly simplify the styling for vertically centered text in any webpage.

Comment: @Narek-T I know this. If you read my question it says `So far i tried digging through the Chromium user agent stylesheets but was not successful. -webkit-appereance: button also did not do the trick.` That means I looked at the Chromium default styles.

Comment: @Narek-T the point is that there is _neither_ padding _nor_ flex used and the text is still centered vertically nevertheless. It would be interesting to know why it does in fact center vertically in order use this exact method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: **It is not possible** to recreate the layout created by a `<button>` element using CSS. Or at least it is hidden really well.

I tested this by changing the display value to flex on a `<button>` and it affected the vertical alignment. Other values like `display:block` did not have an effect. It seems that there is no css value for this, it just is the default behavior and there is no way to do it for a div.

Like you, I was looking for an answer to this question. I was trying to find css property which centers vertically content in button. When I almost gave up I decided to leaf through html specification and this is what I found:

> If the element is an input element, or if it is a button element and
> its computed value for 'display' is not 'inline-grid', 'grid',
> 'inline-flex', or 'flex', then the element's box has a child anonymous
> button content box with the following behaviors:
>
> 1. The box is a block-level block container that establishes a new
>    block formatting context (i.e., 'display' is 'flow-root').
> 2. If the box does not overflow in the horizontal axis, then it is
>    centered horizontally.
> 3. If the box does not overflow in the vertical axis, then it is
>    centered vertically. Otherwise, there is no anonymous button content box.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#button-layout

Comment: Interesting. Do you have codepen or a fiddle on this? If I see it working I can confirm it as the right answer.

Comment: I tested this by changing the display value to flex for button and it affected the vertical alignment. Other values like display block doesn't affect. I just wanted to show you that there is no css value for this, it is just the default behavior and there is no way to do it for a div.

Answer (score -1):

If your button doesn't have a fixed height, you can add padding to the div to center the text vertically. Add `text-align: center;` to center your text horizontally.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Hello!</div>
```

For a button with a fixed height, you may have to have a child element.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.child {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

There are several other methods, but these are the ones I commonly resort to. CSS-Tricks has a complete guide on centering in CSS if you'd like to try out more methods: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear on this - I know methods to center text. There are several. I am curious why the text in a button is centered with respect to a flexible height - without using display flex and padding.